# What is the control flow in React?

Tags: reactjs

How does control flow work in React? Say you have a `Card` component that itself contains `Profile` components that contain `Card` components.

Is the execution simply going one-by-one down the component hierarchy invoking the component functions? Will all `Profile` component functions be invoked before all nested `Card` components? Or will it go into each `Profile` component from the top and resolve each nested `Card`?

Comment: Your site will not run if you do that. It would be an infinite regression which computers really don't like. All your components need a clear, one-way hierarchy. Otherwise you have Card -> Profile -> Card -> Profile -> Card... to infinity...

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/blog/flow-control-in-react/

Comment: @CDoe I'm talking about component functions used non-recursively

Answer (score 0):

You could check the render flow [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-m5mxmu)
Check the console, as you can see it parses all the JS functions with a top-down flow, then it starts to render with a down-top flow.